# Drupal 7 multisite password protect single site

Tags: multi-sites, security, .htaccess, users

I am running a Drupal 7 multisite platform in which sites will be added at a later date to a live version of the website. During the testing process I need the new sites to be on their final live domain but not be viewable by anyone outside of the company.

With single sites we usually achieve this by using the .htaccess and .htpasswd to password project the entire site.

Is there a way to achieve this for induvidual sites on a multisite platform?

Comment: Yep, just set basic auth for the relevant vhosts only, not all of them

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can you provide an example?

Comment: Assuming your web server is apache: http://serverfault.com/questions/127708/how-to-configure-basic-authentication-in-apache-httpd-virtual-hosts